# Pass props to React component stored in a variable extracted out of props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to insert some props to a React component which I have extracted out of props.children, like so:

```
<PageContainer>
  <PageOne />
  <PageTwo />
  <PageThree />
</PageContainer>
```

Inside `<PageContainer>` i am extracting the current page via props.children and current page index, something like this:

```
const { children, pageIndex } = props;
let activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[pageIndex];
```

Inside this PageContainer I have the "oportunity" to send down a function that I need inside the `<PageOne>`, `<PageTwo>` and `<PageThree>`. I tried something like this, but then I got some compiling problems, I think. Since this worked locally and not in my test environment:

```
const newProps = React.cloneElement(activePage.props.children, { myWantedFunction: myWantedFunctionThatIsAvailableInsidePageContainer });
activePage = React.cloneElement(activePage, { children: newProps });
```

The problem here is that `myWantedFunction` is not working in the test environment, but it is working locally. It says that it is not a function in the test environment, but when I console.log it out locally, it prints out a function. I am guessing there is a compiling problem, but I am wondering if there is a better way to acheive this (send down props to a component stored in a variable that I got out of props.children)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, you need to use `React.cloneElement()` to send props down to the child component. First you need to get the active page which you're doing right:

```
let activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[pageIndex];
```

Then you need to use `React.cloneElement` to pass props to this component like this. Let's the name of the prop is `isAuthenticated` which is a boolean:

```
let component = React.cloneElement(activePage, { isAuthenticated: true })
```

Now in your page you'll be able to access this prop: `prop.isAuthenticated`

I created a working demo for you, have a look:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-kowalevski-eh0ic?file=/src/App.js

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also do something like this:

```
const PAGES = [PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree]

function PageContainer(props){
  const {pageIndex} = props
  const ActivePage = PAGES[pageIndex]

  return <ActivePage someFunction={someFunction} />

  function someFunction(){
    // the function you want to pass to the active page
  }
}
```

Node that `ActivePage` has a capital `A`, which allows it to be used as a JSX component.

A drawback of this solution is however that if you use typescript it wont type check the props correctly since you only know which component is to be rendered at runtime. You could replace the array lookup with a switch to avoid that issue.

---

Yet another variation would be to just let the Page components handle their own state and pass the function to all of them. Like this:

```
function PageContainer(props){
  const {pageIndex} = props
  const someFn = () => 0

  return <React.Fragment>
    <PageOne id={1} activePage={pageIndex} someFunction={someFn} />
    <PageTwo id={2} activePage={pageIndex} someFunction={someFn} />
    <PageThree id={3} activePage={pageIndex} someFunction={someFn} />
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

then in the Page Components just check if the pageIndex corresponds to their id:

```
function PageOne(props){
  const {id, activePage, someFunction} = props
  if (id === activePage){
    const result = someFunction()
    return <div>Page One: {result}</div>
  }
}
```